# Let $V_m$ be the vector space of polynomials in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ with degree at most $m$. Then what is the dimension of this vector space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

> Let $V_m$ be the vector space of polynomials in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ with degree at most $m$. Then what is the dimension of this vector space?

I can do this with m<4 maybe. But what is the general formula? It seems that this is a combinatorics problem. But I really do not have idea how to find a formula.

Comment: Consider the set $\{1,X,X^2,...,X^m\}$

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I am so sorry. I typed a wrong title. So the polynomial should be in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. This is more complicated I guess.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, since it does not really appear to be a duplicate of the other question. Note that the given question asks for polynomials of degree *at most* $m$, while the other question considers polynomials of degree *precisely* $m$. The difference is not too big, but still...

Comment: @PhoemueX Agreed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant formulas appear for example in Wendland's "Scattered Data Approximation", part 2 "Haar spaces and multivariate polynomials", Theorem 2.5. In their notation proves for the dimension of $d$-variate polynomials of degree $m$ that $\dim \pi_m(\mathbb{R}^d)={m+d\choose d}$.